# Change font size in WPF compatible with Ease of Access functions

Tags: wpf, accessibility

I am working on a simple WPF app that needs to be accessible for people with impaired vision.

I am testing my app with the `Windows 10 -> Settings -> Ease of Access -> Display -> Make text Bigger` slider setting.

I have some section titles (`TextBlock`) that I want to have a bigger font than the rest of the labels and text in the window. However, if I use the `FontSize` attribute to make it bigger it is no longer affected by changes to the system text size. Thus, while all other text that hasn't `FontSize` set gets bigger, the ones that do remain at their fixed size.

Is there a simple way to make some text relatively bigger than the rest while not setting a specific font size value?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3701) could help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way to make some text relatively bigger than the rest while not setting a specific font size value?

I am afraid there is no support for relative font sizes in WPF but you could try to apply a `ScaleTransform`:

```
<TextBlock Text="Bigger">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.2" ScaleY="1.2" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you, this sort of works, but the solution that dba provided [link](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3701) is better as really scales the font size as opposed to stretching the rendered text, this sometimes producing strange anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

This achieved exactly what I wanted. It is not the prettiest, but it works well.
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3701